# Issues using imap_* methods in PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm starting to write a script to manage some emails for me, but have come across some issues accessing my mailboxes. I can connect fine, with imap_open, and issue commands to the stream returned from it, but only imap_status seems to read the emails correctly.

The imap_status method reports that there are 50 emails in the mailbox, which is correct, but other methods either report 0 messages or have an issue accessing the mailbox, with the message "<no_mailbox>".

This is my script;

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$imapServer = "mail.blah.co.uk";
$imapPort = 143;
$imapFolder = "INBOX";
$imapUsername = "account@blah.co.uk";
$imapPassword = "********";
$serverSpec = imap_utf7_encode ("{" . $imapServer . ":" . $imapPort . "/imap/readonly/debug/notls}" . $imapFolder);

echo "imapServer: $imapServer<br />\n";
echo "imapPort: $imapPort<br />\n";
echo "imapFolder: $imapFolder<br />\n";
echo "imapUsername: $imapUsername<br />\n";
echo "imapPassword: $imapPassword<br />\n";
echo "serverSpec: $serverSpec<br />\n";

if ($imapStream = imap_open($serverSpec, $imapUsername, $imapPassword, OP_HALFOPEN)) {

    $imapStatus = imap_status($imapStream, $serverSpec, SA_ALL);
    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    echo("<pre>imapStatus = " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapStatus, TRUE)) . (is_array($imapErrors) ? "\nERRORS: " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapErrors, TRUE)) : "") . "</pre>");

    $imapCheck = imap_check($imapStream);
    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    echo("<pre>imapCheck = " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapCheck, TRUE)) . (is_array($imapErrors) ? "\nERRORS: " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapErrors, TRUE)) : "") . "</pre>");

    $imapNumMsg = imap_num_msg($imapStream);
    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    echo("<pre>imapNumMsg = " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapNumMsg, TRUE)) . (is_array($imapErrors) ? "\nERRORS: " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapErrors, TRUE)) : "") . "</pre>");

    $imapOverview = imap_fetch_overview($imapStream, "1", 0);
    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    echo("<pre>imapOverview = " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapOverview, TRUE)) . (is_array($imapErrors) ? "\nERRORS: " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapErrors, TRUE)) : "") . "</pre>");

    $imapHeaders = imap_headers($imapStream);
    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    echo("<pre>imapHeaders = " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapHeaders, TRUE)) . (is_array($imapErrors) ? "\nERRORS: " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapErrors, TRUE)) : "") . "</pre>");

    $imapSort = imap_sort($imapStream, SORTARRIVAL, 1, SE_UID);
    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    echo("<pre>imapSort = " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapSort, TRUE)) . (is_array($imapErrors) ? "\nERRORS: " . print_r($imapErrors, TRUE) : "") . "</pre>");

    $imapMailboxMsgInfo = imap_mailboxmsginfo($imapStream);
    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    echo("<pre>imapMailboxMsgInfo = " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapMailboxMsgInfo, TRUE)) . (is_array($imapErrors) ? "\nERRORS: " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapErrors, TRUE)) : "") . "</pre>");

    $mailboxes = imap_getmailboxes($imapStream, $serverSpec, "*");
    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    echo("<pre>mailboxes = " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($mailboxes, TRUE)) . (is_array($imapErrors) ? "\nERRORS: " . htmlspecialchars(print_r($imapErrors, TRUE)) : "") . "</pre>");

    imap_close($imapStream);

} else {

    $imapErrors = imap_errors();
    if (is_array($imapErrors)) { echo("imap_open error: " . print_r($imapErrors, TRUE) . "<br />\n"); }

}

?>
```

and here's the output;

```
imapServer: mail.blah.co.uk
imapPort: 143
imapFolder: INBOX
imapUsername: account@blah.co.uk
imapPassword: ********
serverSpec: {mail.blah.co.uk:143/imap/readonly/debug/notls}INBOX
imapStatus = stdClass Object
(
    [flags] => 31
    [messages] => 50
    [recent] => 0
    [unseen] => 0
    [uidnext] => 77
    [uidvalidity] => 1329686719
)
imapCheck = stdClass Object
(
    [Date] => Thu, 28 Aug 2014 21:40:51 +0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
    [Driver] => imap
    [Mailbox] => {mail.blah.co.uk:143/imap/notls/readonly/user="account@blah.co.uk"}<no_mailbox>
    [Nmsgs] => 0
    [Recent] => 0
)
imapNumMsg = 0
imapOverview = Array
(
)

ERRORS: Array
(
    [0] => Sequence out of range
)
imapHeaders = Array
(
)
imapSort = Array
(
)

ERRORS: Array
(
    [0] => Error in IMAP command received by server.
)
imapMailboxMsgInfo = stdClass Object
(
    [Unread] => 0
    [Deleted] => 0
    [Nmsgs] => 0
    [Size] => 0
    [Date] => Thu, 28 Aug 2014 21:40:51 +0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
    [Driver] => imap
    [Mailbox] => {mail.blah.co.uk:143/imap/notls/readonly/user="account@blah.co.uk"}<no_mailbox>
    [Recent] => 0
)
mailboxes = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => {mail.blah.co.uk:143/imap/readonly/debug/notls}INBOX.Spam
            [attributes] => 64
            [delimiter] => .
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => {mail.blah.co.uk:143/imap/readonly/debug/notls}INBOX.Drafts
            [attributes] => 64
            [delimiter] => .
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => {mail.blah.co.uk:143/imap/readonly/debug/notls}INBOX.Sent
            [attributes] => 64
            [delimiter] => .
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => {mail.blah.co.uk:143/imap/readonly/debug/notls}INBOX.Trash
            [attributes] => 64
            [delimiter] => .
        )

)
```

I'm running this on wampserver running on my local machine. Seeing as it is successfully connecting, I assume that all required modules are already installed...

I have searched for info, but most of the topics I found were solved by appending the correct mailbox name or correcting the syntax of the serverSpec string.

Anyone have any ideas of what may be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out in the end, just an oversight when reading the docs.

On the line

```
$imapStream = imap_open($serverSpec, $imapUsername, $imapPassword, OP_HALFOPEN)
```

The OP_HALFOPEN parameter specifies that a connection should be opened, but not a mailbox. Seeing the connection has no meilbox to read the emails from, it's logical that it reports 0 emails... although I'm not sure why imap_status works differently. Maybe this function defaults to using INBOX is there's no mailbox to work with.